# SQL sort parent rows in table based on child row values

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Given the following table:

```
ID | Name         | Time       | Parent
 1 | Orange       | 1493596800 | 0
 2 | Apple        | 1483228800 | 0
 3 | Red Apple    | 1493596800 | 2
 4 | Yellow Apple | 1493769600 | 2
```

I want to sort my table by descending time of the child rows, and filter the rows such that the Parent must be zero.

**For example:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable as mt1 
 WHERE Parent = 0 
 Order 
    BY 
     ( SELECT mt2.Time 
         FROM MyTable mt2 
        WHERE mt2.Parent = mt1.ID
     Order BY mt2.Time DESC
        Limit 1
     ) DESC
```

**Output must be: **

```
 2 | Apple        | 1483228800 | 0
 1 | Orange       | 1493596800 | 0
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In this case 'Order BY Time DESC' will work directly

Comment: Oracle has ORDER SIBLINGS BY in the CONNECT BY Clause - MySQL - no such love.

Comment: If you need `By time Descendin` order, then "Orange"s row, in your output should first, not second, right ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze By time childs (WHERE parent = Apple)

Comment: The `Time` column that is selected in the correlated subquery needs a prefix (m2?) because m1 and m2 both contain a `Time` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, MAX(c.Time) AS NewestChildTime, p.Parent
FROM MyTable p
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable c
ON c.Parent = p.ID
WHERE p.Parent = 0
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name, p.Parent
ORDER BY NewestChildTime DESC
```

Comment: How i can set when there is no child order by parent time ? You understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* from MyTable a
left join 
(
select a.name,max(b.time) time,b.parent from MyTable a
join MyTable b on b.parent=a.id
where b.parent>0 group by a.name,b.parent 
) b on b.parent=a.id
where a.parent=0
order by b.time desc
```